# Trying to install esint package

Tags: packages, installing, esint

I am trying to install the `esint` package for latex to allow me to use symbols such as the double closed integral (`\oiint`).

I have downloaded the zip archive from [ctan](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/esint/), and extracted it.

In the terminal I ran the following commands:

```
latex esint.ins
(generated esint.sty, uesint.fd, esint10.mf, mathint.mf, bigint.mf)
```

I copied the above 5 files to the root of my texstudio project folder. ie; the same directory where my `.tex` files are which I am editing and compiling with texstudio.

I then ran:

```
mf '\mode=localfont; \input esint10.mf'
(generated esint10.tfm)
```

I also copied this file to the root folder of my texstudio project.

In my tex file I added `\usepackage{esint}`.

On compile, texstudio just says `process exited with errors`. If I remove the line `\usepackage{esint}` then this error disappears.

I think I may have put the files in the wrong locations - perhaps only the `.sty` file should be in the root folder of my texstudio project folder?

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You should not have to install it manually like that.  What platform are you on?

Comment: @Thruston Linux (Fedora with dnf) Can I install it with the package manager?

Comment: Yes. I think fedora provides `texlive-esint` and you probably also want `texlive-esint-type1`

Comment: @Thruston I found `texlive-esint` what is the difference between this and `texlive-esint-type1`?

Comment: @Thruston Apparently `texlive-esint` doesn't work (on compile: process exited with errors, but doesn't specify what these errors are) however if I install `texlive-esint-type1` then it does work?

Comment: The type1 package gives you a scaleable vector version of the font. You still need the base package for the metric files etc. This type of packaging problem is why I moved to mac years ago.

Comment: @Thruston How has moving to mac helped you?

Comment: MacTeX includes everything preconfigured in one big install.

Comment: @Thruston Do you happen to know the package name for ubuntu?

Comment: No I don't know, but Google suggests that esint is included in `texlive-latex-extra`.  But I think I'd just install `texlive-full` so that I had everything available.

Comment: @Thruston Yes I also found that package from a forum somewhere and it seems to be the correct one - I guess it installs a whole load of stuff as it is about 500 MB in size, but I suppose that's not such a big deal as it's very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and you said in comments you were on Fedora which I can't speak for, but Ubuntu 19.04 provides the `texlive-latex-extra` package which includes `esint` and other packages.

`sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra` will install `esint` on Ubuntu.

Comment: The OP wants to work with Fedora, and therefore, I am not sure how your answer would help solving OP's problem. Could you explain?

Comment: The text of the question doesn't specify an OS so I thought I'd give *an* answer even if it's not *the* answer for OP. I found this question from Google and I'm sure other Ubuntu users will as well. No sense forking a different question and answer specifically about Ubuntu when this question is OS agnostic.

Comment: Well I'm not a specialist in this area, but the op mentioned that the focus is for Fedora. Hence, my comment.

Comment: OK... OP doesn't have to select this as the answer, but it is an answer to the question in its current form. I'm not sure what your point is. There can be multiple answers to a question. Detailing something specific to Ubuntu here doesn't hurt anyone.